# Creating a handy separator in tcsh

Tags: linux, shell

In a LifeHacker article they  the show how to add a handy little separator between commands (for bash and mac terminal).  I am trying to get this to work using tcsh on a RHEL though have not been able to get it to work.  I have been unable to get this working under tcsh.  In the instructions, I need to modify the file .bashrc, so I am thinking I need to modify some other file, though I don't have a clue which one I should modify.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

(http://lifehacker.com/5840450/add-a-handy-separator-between-commands-in-your-terminal-on-mac-os-x-and-linux)

Thanks and regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tcsh, you should edit `.tcshrc`. Note that you cannot use the tricks described in the article, because tcsh is too different. You can achieve similar effects with

```
set prompt=---------------------------------------------'%Y/%W/%D %T'\\n%C2%#
```

or

```
alias precmd 'echo -n --------------------------------- ; date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"'
```

I do not know how to do arithmetics in tcsh, so creating the line of the correct length is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, choroba.  That does work well.   I will have to experiment with the various parameters.  BTW: I tried to send the man page for the csh to a text file, but some of the text (looks like the items in bold) get messed up.  Is there a way to send the man page to a text file so I can view is properly??

Comment: @lordhog: What's not proper on `man`? Try googling for `man2txt` or similar.

Comment: that should help.  When I used `man tcsh > tcsh-man.txt` then when I tried to view it, it was additional characters which I assume are a result of the bold formatting of the man page.  The `man2txt` should help me out, thanks.